# Pandas data-frame creation as permutations of 2 series?

Tags: python, pandas, sequences

I have data set with two columns

```
ColA ColB
1    1 
2    2
3    3
```

I want to create resultant frame of

```
ColA ColB
1    1
1    2
1    3
2    1
2    2
2    3
3    1
3    2
3    3
```

Comment: Excellent. can you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `itertools` for this

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
```

Create the original dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3]]*2, index=['ColA', 'ColB']).T
```

Permute the two columns of the dataframe you are interested in:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([e for e in itertools.product(df.ColA, df.ColB)], columns=df.columns)

df2
    ColA  ColB
0   1     1
1   1     2
2   1     3
3   2     1
4   2     2
5   2     3
6   3     1
7   3     2
8   3     3
```